# Matplotlib axvspan shading for pandas DataFrame subplots based on one of the columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, time-series

What is the most elegant way to shade a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) subplots based on one of the columns in a DataFrame?

A simple example:

```
In [8]:
from random import *
import pandas as pd

randBinList = lambda n: [randint(0,1) for b in range(1,n+1)]
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts = pd.DataFrame({'Value1': randn(len(rng)),'Value2': randn(len(rng)),'OnOff': randBinList(len(rng))}, index=rng)
ts.plot(subplots=True)
```

Results in the following plot:

[image: pandas subplots for axvspan]

Ideally, I would like a subplot of just `Value1` and `Value2` with both plots being shaded using [`axvspan`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axhspan_demo.html) where `On` (values with `1.0` in the `OnOff`) are shaded and `Off` is not shaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're set up to do this very well. I think you'll need to interact with matplotlib directly, however.

If you set up your DataFrame like this (what you have already):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

randBinList = lambda n: [np.random.randint(0,2) for b in range(1,n+1)]
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts = pd.DataFrame({
    'Value1': np.random.randn(len(rng)),
    'Value2': np.random.randn(len(rng)),
    'OnOff': randBinList(len(rng))
}, index=rng)
```

Then you you can use the `fill_between` command with the `where` kwarg:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax1.plot(ts.index, ts['Value1'], 'k-')
ax1.fill_between(ts.index, ts['Value1'], y2=-6, where=ts['OnOff'])

ax2.plot(ts.index, ts['Value2'], 'k-')
ax2.fill_between(ts.index, ts['Value2'], y2=-6, where=ts['OnOff'])
fig.tight_layout()
```

Which gives me:
[image: toggle plot]

Comment: FYI: the current `matplotlib 3.7.1` format of the xticklabels: `['01-01 00', '01-01 12', '01-02 00', '01-02 12', '01-03 00', '01-03 12', '01-04 00']`. [See plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKSsw.png)